# How to pass form object from first JSP to second JSP and getting both first & second page form object together in controller when second page submits

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

One JSP page I have one form and once I submit after entering inputs, I want to pass these details (form object) to second JSP page. But I am not displaying the first page detail which I got, in second page. I just want to hold there.

In second JSP page I have another form. When I enter inputs and submit the form in second JSP page. I want to get both first JSP page object and second page object in controller.

### What I have done:

Using Spring MVC, I have set the form object in request scope in controller, when I submit first page. I am able to get the first JSP page form object in the second JSP page. Below is the syntax used to get the object in second jsp page.

```
<%= Object objFirstPage = request.getAttribute("obj1");%>
```

Now how to send this object to controller when I submit second page?

Please tell me the correct approach to achieve this, and correct if my approach is wrong.

Comment: You could consider using Spring WebFlow http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses **MVC** pattern. And your approach to redirect it to another jsp (second.jsp) is totally meaningless. you can instead put the data in the `session` so that it will be available through out the user the session .

Spring doesnt provide `@viewscope` like jsf implicitly , which would allow you to hold data between consecutive pages. you can find an example here on [adding a JSF view Scope to Spring scope support](http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/adding_a_jsf_view_scope).

Comment: thanks San. putting the data in session and proceeding.

Comment: we1come :) . glad i could help :)